# Laravel Livewire drag and drop giving issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

It is my first project in laravel.
I want to drag and drop the tr in table as needed.
in this the tr is not getting dragged. I don't know what I did wrong.
Please help.
There are no errors in console. sorry for making it go very long.

In my books.blade.php I have code like this

```
 <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr class="sticky">
                                        <th></th>
                                        <th>Image</th>
                                        <th>Title (English) </th>
                                        <th>Title (Native) </th>
                                        <th>Religion</th>
                                        <th>Status </th>
                                        <th>Action </th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                
                                <tbody id="myTable" wire:sortable="updateBookOrder">
                                    @foreach ($booksData as $book)
                                        <tr wire:sortable.item="{{ $book->id }}" wire:key="book-{{ $book->id }}">
                                            <td wire:sortable.handle style="width: 10px; cursor: move;">
                                                <i class="fa fa-arrows-alt text-muted"></i>
                                            </td>
                                            <td onclick="window.location='{{ url('/admin/chapters/'.$book->id) }}';">
                                                <img id="preview-image" src="{{ url('dist/books/' . $book->img) }}"
                                                    alt="" height="100px" width="100px">
                                            </td>
                                            <td  onclick="window.location='{{ url('/admin/chapters/'.$book->id) }}';">
                                                    {{ $book->title }}
                                            </td>
                                            <td onclick="window.location='{{ url('/admin/chapters/'.$book->id) }}';">
                                                    {{ $book->titlenative }}
                                            </td>
                                            <td onclick="window.location='{{ url('/admin/chapters/'.$book->id) }}';">
                                                    {{ $book->religion }} ({{ $book->religionnative }})
                                            </td>                                          
                                            <td style="width: 25px;">
                                                <input data-id="{{ $book->id }}" data-forwhat="books"
                                                    class="toggle-class" type="checkbox" data-onstyle="success"
                                                    data-offstyle="danger" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Active"
                                                    data-off="Inactive" {{ $book->status ? 'checked' : '' }}>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <div class="dropdown">
                                                    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button"
                                                        id="actionsDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
                                                        aria-expanded="false">
                                                        Actions
                                                    </button>
                                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="actionsDropdown">
                                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item"
                                                                href="{{ url('/admin/books/' . $book->id) }}">Edit</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-toggle="modal"
                                                                data-target="#modal-default{{ $book->id }}"> Delete
                                                            </a></li>
                                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item"
                                                                href="{{ url('/admin/books/chapter/' . $book->id) }}">
                                                                Add Chapter
                                                            </a></li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                        
                                        </tr>
                                    

                                        


                                        <div class="modal fade" id="modal-default{{ $book->id }}">
                                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                                                <div class="modal-content">
                                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                                        <h4 class="modal-title">Default Modal</h4>
                                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                                                            aria-label="Close">
                                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                                        </button>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                                        <p>Are you sure you want to delete??</p>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="modal-footer justify-content-between">
                                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
                                                            data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                                        <a href="{{ url('/admin/deletebooks/' . $book->id) }}">
                                                            <button type="button"
                                                                class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>
                                                        </a>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <!-- /.modal-content -->
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
                                        </div>
                        </div>
                        @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                        </table>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        console.log('jQuery is loaded!');
        $('.toggle-class').change(function() {
            var status = $(this).prop('checked') == true ? 1 : 0;
            var forwhat = $(this).data('forwhat') || 'books';
            var id = $(this).data('id');
            var token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                url: '/changeStatus',
                data: {
                    'status': status,
                    'id': id,
                    'forwhat': forwhat,
                    '_token': token
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data.success)

                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    console.error(xhr.responseText);
                }
            })
        });
    });
</script>
@include('admin.layouts.footer')
```

and I have this code in footer.blade.php

```
{{-- Livewire --}}
@livewireScripts

{{-- Livewire Sortable --}}
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/livewire/sortable@v3.x.x/dist/livewire-sortable.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="{{url('plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
```

and this code in controller

```
function updateBookOrder($items){
        $model = new ReligionModel;
        foreach($items as $item){
            $model ->setTable('books')->find($item['value'])->update(['order_position' => $item['order']]);
        }
        $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('updated',['message' => 'Books Sorted Successfully']);

    }
```